# Heroku Bash Script not working on Crontab

Tags: bash, heroku, cron, heroku-cli

I really can't see what's wrong here. I have a Digital Ocean droplet that runs a bash script every 10 mins to get some records from my DB of a Heroku slug. This is my script:

```
# /bin/sh
echo "Starting pull from postgres ..."
heroku pg:psql dbname --app app --command "COPY (select wallet from wallets where tokens_sent > 0) TO STDOUT WITH CSV" > wallets.csv
```

It gets all wallets and save them in the `wallets.csv` file. If I run this script in the terminal with `sh get_tokens.sh`, everything works fine! For some unknown reason, when I put this script in my crontab, it doesn't pull the data from Heroku.

I'm a root user and the root user is running the script. Below are the file permissions:

```
 4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   782 Feb  3 18:18 get_tokens.sh
16 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12318 Feb  3 18:21 wallets.csv
```

Here is my crontab record:

```
10 * * * * bash ~/get_tokens.sh >> logs.txt
```

I added the logs.txt to see if potentially some error would pop up but nothing seems wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Standard cron job troubleshooting: capture errors as well as regular output with `>> logs.txt 2>&1`. Also, cron jobs run with a really minimal environment; what environmental dependencies does your script (and heroku itself) have? Does it work if you run it with `env -i bash ~/get_tokens.sh` (which is not the same as a cron job's environment, but closer than normal)?

Comment: Thanks a lot @GordonDavisson. Thx to you I found the real reason why I was having issues. I got `heroku not found`. For some reason the script couldn't read the `snap/bin/` folder in order to find the heroku bin. I added the complete path and the issue was gone

Comment: That's a really common problem in cron jobs. One of the things that's minimal in a cron job's environment is `PATH` (i.e. the list of places to look for command binaries) -- it's generally just /bin and /usr/bin, so anything outside those won't be found unless you set `PATH` or use explicit paths to binaries.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't providing an absolute path to `wallets.csv`:

```sh
# /bin/sh
echo "Starting pull from postgres ..."
heroku pg:psql dbname --command "COPY... TO STDOUT WITH CSV" > wallets.csv
```

That file is relative to whatever the current working directory is, which probably isn't the directory you expect. I suggest you provide a full path:

```sh
# /bin/sh
echo "Starting pull from postgres ..."
heroku pg:psql dbname --command "COPY... TO STDOUT WITH CSV" > /path/to/wallets.csv
```

Or you can `cd` into the right directory:

```sh
# /bin/sh
echo "Starting pull from postgres ..."
cd /path/to/some/directory
heroku pg:psql dbname --command "COPY... TO STDOUT WITH CSV" > wallets.csv
```

See [What is the 'working directory' when cron executes a job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38951/12606) on Unix & Linux.